# I have to dispatch the action after closing tab event but it not work dispatch action

Tags: javascript

I have to dispatch the action after closing tab event but it not work dispatch action take long time for operation and tab closed before performing operation

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
  });



 const alertUser = (event) => {

    dispatch(cartActions.destroyOrderAndClear())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error");
      });
  };
```

Comment: `dispatch` is an async function so the tab would be closed before it is done.